# Share point list: Do not allow duplicate values in column B if it has same value in Column A

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list

I have a Share point list with two columns:

[image]

It should not allow to save and throw an error if a duplicate entry is made in Column 2 (Technology) when the value in Column 1 (Name) is the same i.e. Same person cannot enter the same technology twice.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is no OOB feature that could make a row unique. For classical experience, you could use [CSR](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1205585/Unique-Entries-Based-on-Multiple-Columns-in-Sharep) or other js customization to validate the edit form. For other cases, I think the only available option is [Remote event receiver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/use-remote-event-receivers-in-sharepoint).

- [Building a Remote Event Receiver is Easy](https://derekgusoff.wordpress.com/2017/11/08/remote-event-receivers-youre-all-doing-it-wrong/)
- [Cancel an item event](https://www.thesharepointguide.com/remote-event-receivers-rer-in-sharepoint-online/)

BR

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Just one query, would this work with Sharepoint Online?